# How can I access element of complicated model in jquery?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp

I'm making a jsp site with spring mvc.

```
protected String[] complexProperty = null;//    ["something","something's value"]
```

in controller I added

```
model.addAttribute("SetProperties", arrays);//where arrays is [] of complexProperties = [[1,a],[2,b],[]...]
```

in javascript(jquery) in jsp site I wanted to access concrete elements like

```
var complexProperty = '${SetProperties[0][0]}';// will give me 1
alert(whichTable+"  complex:"+complexProperty2);
```

Now I want to print them in for loop, so I need to change those [0][0] dynamicly somehow. but I cant figure out how to do it
I already tried

```
var temp=0;
var complexProperty = '${SetProperties[temp][temp]}';
var complexProperty = '${SetProperties["temp"]["temp"]}';
var complexProperty = '${SetProperties[${"temp"}][${"temp"}]}';
var complexProperty = '${SetProperties["${temp}"]["${temp}"]}';
```

but none of them gave me 1, either error or something strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing JSP variables with Javascript variables. The best way would be if your javascript code call backend to retrieve JSON object and use it later on like any other javascript object.

If you have/want to use object from http request attribute in your Javascript code it's better to serialize it to JSON in JSP page.

Depending on what's on your classpath (Jackson/GSON) you can do it in a way (GSON example):

```
<%@ page import="com.google.gson.Gson" %>
<% Gson gson = new Gson(); %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var setProperties = <%= gson.toJson(request.getAttribute("setProperties")) %>
</script>
```

If GSON is not on your classpath don't forget to add it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can iterate over `setProperties` in the way you want, for example:

```
for (var key in setProperties) {
    console.log(key, setProperties[key]);
}
```

Another way is to create your own JSP function like described here: http://thinkinginsoftware.blogspot.com.es/2013/02/custom-jsp-taglib-to-convert-object-to.html

Comment: thank you very much your code worked. are there any differences between jackson json and google json ?

Comment: They are both used to serialize/deserialize Java objects to/from JSON, so the concepts are more or less the same but different implementation. The thing is that if you use Spring MVC and you do already something with JSON, most probably Jackson is already on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Never worked with JSP but maybe you can move on from this:

```
var complexProperty = ${SetProperties};

$.each(complexProperty, function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

[jQuery.each documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)